# Staple through a small electrical wire, will it still work correctly?

Tags: electrical

I'm running a small cable along a wooden beam, using a staple gun. I accidentally put the staple through one of the wires (the one with the black stripe).

It's very small gauge wire and the hole is all the way through. More worried because it's an electrical wire from a  solar panel, going to an outdoor security light.

How will the hole in the wire effect current and ultimately charging of the batteries on the unit? The picture is a bit blurry but you can see the hole in the wire.

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: That's typical wire, i.e.; romex, is it? How wide is it across the view we have here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong kind of staples. Eventually they might all abrade the cable, whether or not you stapled right through it and present a fire hazard. Replacing the cable would be best. Inspecting the damage would be good, but then you'd have a splice to deal with or have to re-insulate, both having to be waterproof. Damaged insulation can be fixed, but we don't know how bad the wire got nicked (also a fire hazard).

Plastic Insulated Cable Staples: ([Ideal](http://www.idealind.com/products/wire_management/cable_staples/plastic_insul_cable_staples.jsp))

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You'll have reduced the cross-section of the conductor. That will reduce the conductivity and safety of the wire.

You should cut out that part and reconnect the working wires again. This should be inside a junction box.

Otherwise you will need to run a new wire.

Answer (score 2):

Solar panel, security light and the looks of that cable... sounds like a low voltage wire. You don't need to have those splices in a box unless it's in your local code for some reason. Check to make sure. Just use the appropriate splice connectors depending if it's indoor (something like Scotchlok) or outdoor.

Might be easier/better/cheaper in the long run to just get new wire and use the appropriate wire staples as @Mazura suggested. You shouldn't be stapling wires down with regular staples like that.